# Handle children when subclassing gtk::Container in Rust

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk3, gtk-rs

I am trying to create a custom gtk container containing multiple children using the Rust binding for gtk. I derive my custom class from `gtk::Container` and `gtk::Widget`. The problem is as follows:

`gtk::subclass::container::ContainerImpl` ([documentation](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/subclass/container/trait.ContainerImpl.html)) only provides a few methods to implement. Those methods include the `add` and `remove` methods required to make the container able to handle children.
My subclass uses its own vector of widgets which is filled by the `add` method. Custom size negotiation and allocation is implemented and works as expected. For the most parts, I followed [this tutorial](http://ptomato.name/advanced-gtk-techniques/html/custom-container.html) (which is for plain C). **But the `get_children` method does not work, it returns an empty vector.** This is expected as the method uses the `forall` and `foreach` methods which do not know about my custom storage of widgets. But those methods are parts of `gtk::ContainerExt` and thus not definable by my subclass (at least without implementing all associated methods manually). The tutorial I followed overrides those methods.

I do not know how to proceed as it feels like the children not being correctly registered may lead to later memory leaks and as it renders some methods like `get_children` useless. Does gtk-rs have any special functionality for handling children? I am unable to find any documentation in this direction. But there must be a possibility as subclassing a container without being able to handle children is nearly useless.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the current stable release of gtk-rs is not sufficient to implement custom containers as `forall` and `foreach` are needed but not defined in the interface. This will be fixed soon and already is in the gtk-rs git ([source](https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk/issues/1036)). If you need to implement `forall` (`foreach` will also depend on the same interface) and it still is not available in the stable release, just use the git-repo of gtk-rs as dependency source in your `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: This is now officially released for a long time, do you have some example source-code?